# Disable system services to save data

Tags: iphone, ios, cellular-data

Is there any way I could disable the system services that use data when I am **not** connected to wifi?

[image]

Comment: so the....     Double tap the home button to bring up the multi-tasking view.
    Swipe-up the screenshot of the app you want to exit.
--> does not work for you ?

Comment: @Buscar How does that work for system services?

Comment: In 2018 with iPhone 7 on the latest iOS this is happening for me. It's the 22nd and It's used 1.8GB. I'm up to 6.2GB total. This is ridiculous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, as long as your iDevice is not jailbroken, sadly there is no way to fully do that, but you can disable some of them here:

Settings > Privacy > Location Services > scroll all the way down to the bottom > System Services

[image: System Settings]

(At least with the iOS versions up to 7)

Comment: This is for location services, not for cellular data usage. These options have no impact on the system services shown in Cellular/Mobile.

Comment: "Well, as long as your iDevice is not jailbroken, sadly there is no way to fully do that, but you can disable some of them(=System Services) here" He'd ask for disabling System Services, didn't he? I told him that there is no way to fully do that.

Comment: OP asked 'disable the system services that use data' — the system services in that list are for location services and are unrelated to cellular data usage.

Answer (score 2):

Just take out the SIM card and put it back in. That resolved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can't select which system services have access to 3G from that page. Many system services' data use can't be switched off—only the services themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Settings>iCloud>iCloudDrive>Use mobile data. Turn it off. All other cellular datas you need to turn off are already mentioned in the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with user185442. This seems to be impossible. I spent a long time disabling data traffic for all non vital apps and services, including things like Music, iBooks, App Store and a large number of 3rd party apps. I still got 912 MB "System Services" usage in an afternoon. The culprit (apart from Apple's programmers) seems to be iTunes purchases, that probably somehow were downloaded over 3G, even though Mobile Data was disabled for iTunes & App Stores.

Answer (score -1):

1. Turn off the Cellular Data for the apps which are not important.
2. Make sure the backup on cloud is not via celluar
3. Go To "Reset" and click on "Reset Network Settings".
4. After Resetting "General" option will not appear in your System Services.