# Why my messaging services consume a lot of data recently?

Tags: iphone

I found a similar [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/305070/ios-system-services-time-location-uses-excessive-cellular-data-why-how-to). But mine is regarding with **Messaging Services**. As you see the total data used is about 4.5GB. 4GB of them is used in recent two months. The **Messaging Services** is using about 2.4GB. I want to know why and how to disable **Messaging Services** because my phone is running in a private 4G network and we never use iMessage or Text Message etc.

[image]

Comment: "private 4G network"? You mean one that isn't connected to the rest of the world?

Comment: What are you sending?  Video?  Pictures?  Do you have lots of attachments?

Comment: Time & Location using 1.3 GB? That’s a little odd, too.

Comment: @IconDaemon Because I turned on real time location tracking even when app is in background.

Comment: @Allan I didn't do anything. Only one application is running which is monitor the location change.

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes. It's only connected to the server in this private network for security reason.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can check iMessage apps that appear in App tray in Messages (or look for a button with App Store logo beside the text field).
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206906

Are there any? If yes, you must check them.
Second, if you say that you "never use iMessage", you can turn it off in Settings.

Comment: Actually iMessage is turned off. That's why I don't understand why **Messaging Services** took so much data.

Comment: My guess would have been that it's 'wasting data' trying repeatedly to connect to a service it cannot reach - but idk how that would apply if it's switched off entirely.

Comment: MMS Messaging also?